# How do I check that a SQL Server linux database is up and running?

Tags: sql-server, linux, database

I have a Docker-based application that is running against a SQL Server Linux database docker container. In the startup of the application container I want to check if the database is up and available before starting up the application. What is the correct way either using `sqlcmd` or other methodology, to tell that the SQL Server database is up and running?

I'm looking for something equivalent to the `mysqladmin ping` functionality which checks for mysql database availability.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar use-case, and ended up using writing my own script using `sqlcmd`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..20};
do
    # Check if Database already exists
    RESULT=`sqlcmd -S <db-address> -U <username> -P <password> -Q "IF DB_ID('DatabaseName') IS NOT NULL print 'YES'"`
    CODE=$?
    
    if [[ $RESULT == "YES" ]]
    then
        echo "Do Something."
        break
    
    elif [[ $CODE -eq 0 ]] && [[ $RESULT == "" ]]
    then
        echo "If this comes up, the database doesn't exist"
        break
        
    # If the code is different than 0, an error occured. (most likely database wasn't online) Retry.
    else
        echo "Database not ready yet..."
        sleep 1
    fi
done
```

`$CODE` equals a `0`, when the command ran successfully. If the database is down, it will probably takes a couple of seconds until the command timeouts, and then you'll get a `$CODE` which is not zero.